# How to get method details?

Tags: c#, .net

how can I find the method working details (method description) in visual Studio 2012 for C# something like method description in eclips for java which give the method signature and the list of overloaded method and the description for what purpose this method is made.

Answer (score 2):

If XML comments are added up on the method then you will see those in Visual studio intellisense. Otherwise you will see method's parameters and its overloaded forms. XML comments can be added to the method with `///` Something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Some method description to show in intellisense. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parameter1"></param>
/// <param name="parameter2"></param>
public static void SomeMethod(int parameter1, int parameter2)
{
}
```

Shortcut is to press `/` forward slash three times and it will appear on the Method. It will appear like:

[image]

You may see more about: [XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)

Comment: thanx for your reply, basically I am looking for predefined method description , what a particular method will do. is there some add-on or plugin in like eclips that we need to add to get method description here in Visual Studio as well?

Comment: @SohailAnwerFaruqui, I am not too sure about eclipse, but What do mean by method description ?? the one added by you or you want some autogenerated description ?

Comment: I need autogenerated description for library methods.
In eclips after including the libraries the description of the method will be visible after mouseover on them. I am not sure weather this feature is available in C# even. I know mouse over in C# will give use method signature and the overloaded ones , but the functionality of method is not described.

Answer (score 0):

`Right click` on the method and select `Go to Definition`. OR use `F12`.

Answer (score 0):

If You Configure you'r visual studio as c# you can press contrl+shift+space when your cursor is in the middle of method's parenthesis  , then you can see the method overloads and ...